# Error of react native: "react native unexpected keyword 'const' issue"

Tags: react-native

**Hello dears,**

has anyone known how to solve this issue?
node version: 7.9.0
npm: 5.3.0
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.52.0"

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you need, and what have you tried. This is a very broad question and it could happen by a lot of problems. Please post your code, and what have you tried to solve it so everyone could help you.

Comment: Having the same problem I want to ask what you did to resolve it? Could you please answer your own question?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get any solution?>